# iOS - Some UIViews inside UIScrollview not receiving touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I am programmatically adding views to UIScrollView. Problem is only those views are responding to touch that are initially visible on the iPad. If I scroll to views that are outside iPad's screen initially and click them, nothing happens. Following is how my view controller looks like; note that I am not using Auto Layout.

[image]

And following is how I am setting the touch for my custom view that is subclass of UIButton:

```
[myView addTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanelClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Check whether your views are not  outside of the superview's bounds. You could use the view debugger for this or enable `Clip Subviews` to all the superviews of the views that do not receive touches.

Comment: What is myView over here?

Comment: @RajTandel my customer buttom that is subclass of UIButton.

Comment: @hrehman can you please share your code of how you are adding buttons in scrollview.

Comment: @RajTandel by simply calling addSubview.

Comment: @hrehman yes i know that. I just want to know that where you are doing allocation of buttons. Piece of code would be much helpful to find out the issues.

Comment: @Jelly your comment helped me to find the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Jelly comment, I noticed that the view inside scrollview that holds all the subviews was not being resized properly. Following is how it looked initially ... when visible subviews on screen properly handled touch.

[image]

And following is how it looked when I scrolled to bottom ... note that PanelsView is not resized properly to contain all the subviews:-

[image]

Looks like I only needed to adjust the height of PanelsView to match its child (*viewPanelContainer*) height which is what i did in below line after panelsView finished its drawing:-

```
_panelsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _panelsView.frame.size.width, _panelsView.viewPanelContainer.frame.size.height);
```